# Wordpress how to register global object before executing cron, so it's usable during cron job?

Tags: wordpress

I have some background workers in Wordpress which are registered as global variables during `init` hook. Everything is ok until I'm trying to reference the workers during a cron job, they are undefined.
The cron job, if you are asking yourself what's the purpose of this, basically is looking if there are jobs to do, and if yes it's enqueueing them in the background worker.

So since the `init` hook seems to not run before executing cron job, what is the best hook if there is one, where i can register my workers earlier?

If there is a way I'd like to go on Wordpress way, without setting my own cron implementation with external trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the priority of your action hook that registers the globals on init to a value below 10.

```
add_action('init', 'my_function_that_registers_global_variables', 9)
```

Source with more details: https://konstantin.blog/2013/tip-wp_cron-runs-during-init/